# AngularJS and an issue with Persian(Arabic) characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, arabic, persian

I am using AngularJS in my project and it works correctly in English, but when I want for example get result from query searching I encounter with error in console:

## in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>project</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="info.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="CompanyInfo">
    <label for="search">
        <input type="text" ng-model="query" id="search"/>
    </label>
    <select name="select" id="">
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="founder">Founder</option>
    </select>
    <label for=""><input ng-model="direction" name="direction" value="reverse" type="radio"/>Descending</label>
    <label for=""><input ng-model="direction" name="direction" type="radio"/>Ascending</label>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in inform | limitTo: 10 | filter: query | orderBy: query:direction">{{item.name | uppercase}}, {{item.founder}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## JS:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.controller('CompanyInfo', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.inform = data;
    });
}]);
```

## Error:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%200-0%20%5B%D8%B9%5D&p2=%D8%B9
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:6:416
    at ec.throwError (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:198:58)
    at ec.lex (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:196:481)
    at Object.s.ast (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:201:465)
    at Object.rd.compile (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:211:146)
    at fc.parse (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:237:178)
    at $get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:116:396)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:157:207
    at Array.map (native)
```

## JSON:

```
[
  {
  "name": "booking online 1",
  "founder": "Alri"
  },
  {
  "name": "booking online 2",
  "founder": "Reza Valimoradi"
  },
  {
  "name": "booking online 3",
  "founder": "Alirezari"
  },
  {
  "name": "booking online 4",
  "founder": "Ali"
  },
  {
  "name": "booking online 5",
  "founder": "Ghaffari"
  },
  {
  "name": "رزرو اینترنتی",
  "founder": "غفاری"
  },
  {
  "name": "اینترنت",
  "founder": "مرادی"
  }
]
```

It is neccessary to do it, what should I do?

Comment: What does `data.json` look like? Is it [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: It shows it correctly but it can't search in it.

Comment: So you're saying you only get the error if you type "ع" (for example) into the search box?

Comment: no for every character in Persian!

Comment: Your `orderBy` filter looks wrong. I don't think you want `query` in there

Comment: It works for English! :)  Why?

Comment: Probably because it has no problem parsing plain ASCII into an `orderBy` expression, even if it doesn't match any of your object properties. You really just want to use `orderBy:'name':reverse`, where `reverse` is boolean `true` or `false`